# Какой вид предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Ценится что и как мы изображаем.

Это сложное предложение, и после "ценится" должна быть запятая?

Answer (score 2):

Виды предложений разные бывают – по цели высказывания, например. Или по эмоциональной окраске.

В нашем случае – по количеству грамматических основ. Простые – одна основа, сложные – две или более.

Первая основа – ценится (кем-либо), вторая – мы изображаем; запятая в этом СПП нужна.

***Ценится, что и как мы изображаем.***

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении:

**Ценится, что и как мы изображаем.**

**Исключение:** придаточное выражено **только союзным словом** и отсутствует его логическое выделение.

Сравнить:

Непонятно, **что и как там происходит.**

Ну, вот и объясни мне **что и как**. Сам рассуждай, **что и как.**